# Visual C++ for Linux: copy content files to build directory?

Tags: linux, visual-c++, build

I have a Visual C++ for Linux project in VS2017 that I'm building on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. This project consists of a single source file (main.c) and an image (test.jpg). When building the project, I want the image file to also be deployed to the pi, so that the code in main.c can do something with it locally. However, I can't figure out how to do this

The image file's Content property is set to True, as is Included in Project. In the project properties, under Copy Sources, Sources to Copy is set to "@(SourcesToCopyRemotely)" and Copy Sources is set to "Yes". However, when I build, only main.c is copied to the Pi, and the compiler output is just a single .out file. I hoped to also see test.jpg there, but alas.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project) mentions that @(SourcesToCopyRemotely) defaults to all files in the project. However, when I evaluate the value of @(SourcesToCopyRemotely, it evaluates to just "main.c".

How do I make sure content files in my projects also end up in the build directory, along with the .out file? Preferably without having to manually enter each filename in a post-build step.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is a bug in VC++ for Linux. A workaround, currently, is to use Additional Sources to copy. There's a caveat though: it doesn't work with remote paths that start with ~. So you can't use $(RemoteRootDir) if the Remote Build Root Directory setting is set to the default of "~/projects".

I've currently got Remote Build Root Directory set to "/home/pi/projects" and for each file I want to copy to the build directory I set Additional Sources to Copy to "[filename]:=$(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName)/bin/$(Platform)/$Configuration)/[filename]". For instance:

```
firstimage.png:=$(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName)/bin/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)/firstimage.png;secondimage.png:=$(RemoteRootDir)/$(ProjectName)/bin/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)/secondimage.png
```

Comment: I don't know if it's fair to call it a bug. This functionality seems to be called out on purpose in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/configure-a-linux-project#copy-sources 

"By default, the @(SourcesToCopyRemotely) defaults to all source code files in the project, but does not include any asset/resource files, such as images."

Comment: It is defintly bug. My header files (*.h) dont copy to remote machine because ı make them custom build tool file type (with all remote copy options setted to yes). But still it doesn't copy to remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

Right-clicking on the non-source code file to open it's properties page and flagging as `Content` in the `General` tab will cause the file to be copied to the remote. There is no need to add anything to the `Copy Sources` tab. The `Copy Sources` page of the project properties must show the default of `@(SourcesToCopyRemotely)`. And when you edit this setting the macro should show an expansion with the additional files included.

I have found that it necessary to refresh the macro by clearing `Source to Copy` and then restoring it to the default **after** you have marked the additional files as content.

I have encountered problems when the additional files are not in the same folder as the C++ source files on the Windows host and/or you want to put them somewhere else on the remote. There are several open issues on the VCLinux GitHub site [like this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/85) so it will be worth reporting any problems you have on there.

[VCLinux 1.0.6 on VS Pro 2017 + Debian Jessie remote]

Comment: I cannot get this to work on VS 2017 Community. Even clearing the setting, building, restoring it and building it again does not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The "Pre-Build Event" section of the project properties offers "Additional Files To Copy". Addressing my file there (relative to the solution) showed following in the output when building:

```
Copying file 'C:\myfilepath\resource.png' to '/home/pi/projects/myproject/resource.png'
```

It is possible to move the files to the final destination then with Remote Post-Build Events (mv source destination). Not the most elegant way, but the first thing I got working..